# Selenium Python: Invalid Selector in find_element_by_css_selector (Error)

Tags: css, python-3.x, python-2.7, selenium, web-scripting

I'm doing an automation to search a certain process on a website and collect information. When requesting data collection, it returns the following error:
**"Selenium Python: Invalid Selector in find_element_by_css_selector"**

this is my code: chrome.find_element_by_css_selector('#\31 641215964292-0-uiGrid-003J-cell > div').text

This is the page source in the website: [image]

In yellow is the data I need to extract.

The id "\31" appears to contain the wrong value. But in that case how can I extract the data like this?

I would like to know the reason and solution.

Thanks for your time.

Please help me.

Comment: remove the css tag, it implies that you need help with styling

Comment: Please [edit the question](/posts/70566746/edit) to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
elem=chrome.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='ui-grid-canvas']/div[2]/div/div/div").text
```

Would get you the first element with that number. It doesn't look like they have any unique identifiers except maybe the ui grid cell id.

Answer (score 1):

Try this css:

find_element_by_css_selector(".ui-grid-cell-contents .ng-binding .ng-scope")

If it's still not working, you can use xpath to check selenium can actually locate the element.